# How can we add an element, and make it fade in, not using jQuery or CSS transition, but just use CSS animation?

Tags: javascript, css-animations

Given the following code, how would we add the element and make it fade in using CSS animation?

I have one solution which I will post two days from today.

It seems that if we use CSS transition, we need to use some mechanism that is similar to `setTimeout()` and is not as clean.  The following code adds the element without fading in:

```js
const tableElement = document.querySelector("#tbl");

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", ev => {
  tableElement.innerHTML = (
    `${tableElement.innerHTML}<tr><td>Hi There ${Math.random()}</td></tr>`
  );
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<table id="tbl"></table>
```

Comment: You should probably add your solution as an answer today to save people from the effort of coming up with the same answer.

Comment: @Nick I can see that perspective, although somebody may suggest I can let people have some fun and have the change of getting reputation and if the answer is simple and good, getting accepted as the answer

Comment: That seems reasonable too. It's beyond my level of css expertise, but I'm following to see what others come up with.

Comment: @Nick that's great... that's like having fun in programming, not like when I go to an interview, they don't know the answer too but they are holding the paper with the solution and when I cannot give the answer, disqualify me right there

Comment: :) plus, I might well learn something useful!

Comment: @Nick there are a couple of solutions now

Answer (score 1):

I used tbody:last-child to target the tr because the browser adds a tbody (at least chrome and firefox)

```js
const tableElement = document.querySelector("#tbl");

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", ev => {
  tableElement.innerHTML = (
    `${tableElement.innerHTML}<tr><td>Hi There ${Math.random()}</td></tr>`
  );
});
```

```css
@keyframes fade {
      0% { opacity: 0; }
      100% { opacity: 1; }
  }

  table tbody:last-child tr {
      background: red;
      animation: fade 1s;
  }
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<table id="tbl"></table>
```

Comment: ah, ok, good solution although, in some usage, the item added could be in the middle of a table or some random element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you use DOM scripting or innerHTML to do it, it might be slightly different.  But the idea is to use `animation`, `@keyframes`, and if you want the animation to stay, use `forwards`.  You usually would like to remove the `new` class (or any class name you use to denote a new row) that added the animation, unless if it is some framework that have the `new` there without re-rendering the DOM element and does not cause it to animate again, in which case it is optional to remove `new`. The following has the animation intentionally set to a longer duration, so that the changes can be seen more clearly:

#### Wanting the animation to stay:

```js
const tableElement = document.querySelector("#tbl");

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", ev => {
  tableElement.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach(e => e.classList.remove("new"));
  tableElement.innerHTML = `${tableElement.innerHTML}<tr class="new"><td>Hi There ${Math.random()}</td></tr>`;
});
```

```css
tr.new {
  animation: 2s forwards fadein;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    background: #ff6;
    opacity: 0
  }

  to {
    background: #ff6;
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<table id="tbl"></table>
```

#### Making it fade in, and back to normal:

```js
const tableElement = document.querySelector("#tbl");

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", ev => {
  tableElement.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach(e => e.classList.remove("new"));
  tableElement.innerHTML = `${tableElement.innerHTML}<tr class="new"><td>Hi There ${Math.random()}</td></tr>`;
});
```

```css
tr.new {
  animation: 2s fadein;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    background: #ff6;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    background: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<table id="tbl"></table>
```